# What is the order of evaluation in a member initializer list?

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, initialization, c++-faq

I have a constructor that takes some arguments. I had assumed that they were initialized in the order listed, but in one case, it appears they were being initialized in reverse, resulting in an abort. When I reversed the arguments, the program stopped aborting.

Below is an example of the syntax I'm using. `a_` needs to be initialized before `b_` in this case. Can you ensure this order of initialization?

```cpp
class A
{
  public:
    OtherClass a_;
    AnotherClass b_;

    A(OtherClass o, string x, int y)
      : a_(o)
      , b_(a_, x, y) {}
};
```

Comment: You say you're asking about constructor arguments, but they're evaluated before you ever reach the constructor, and they're evaluated in an unspecified, compiler-determined order. But you're really asking about the order of initialization lists, so I've changed the question title for you.

Comment: I was asked this question in an interview :)

Comment: The interviewer probably got the question from here :)

Comment: @hookenz No, we didn't.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

It depends on the order of data member declarations in the class. So `a_` will be the first one, then `b_` will be the second one in your example.

Comment: In fact, good compilers will warn if you have a different order in the declaration versus the constructor initialiser list. For example, see `-Wreorder` in gcc.

Comment: The reason for which they are constructed in the member declaration order and not in the order in the constructor is that one may have several constructors, but there is only one destructor.  And the destructor destroy the members in the reserse order of construction.

Comment: did we mean ...reverse order of declaration. Not of "construction", the destructor cannot possibly see into the constructor to know can it?

Comment: @user337598 yes, sort of. I think AProgrammer meant "construction" in the sense of actual physical initialization (which as you suggest occurs in the order of declaration), and _not_ in the sense of "order appearing in some constructor's init list". Your wording is clearer.

Answer (score 224):

To quote the standard, for clarification:

> 12.6.2.5
>
> Initialization shall proceed in the following order:
>
> **...**
>
> - Then, nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>     (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> **...**

Answer (score 32):

The [standard reference](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf) for this now appears to be 12.6.2 section 13.3:

> (13.3) — Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).

Answer (score 0):

Seeing other answers without to much details into other members initialization I recommend reading more info from [standard reference](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf) 12.6.2 section 13 (thanks @Adam Getchell for link):

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> (13.1) — First, and only for the **constructor of the most derived class** (1.8),
> **virtual base classes are initialized in
> the order they appear** on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes,
> where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class *base-specifier-list*.
>
> (13.2) — Then, **direct base classes** are initialized in declaration order 
> **as they appear in the *base-specifier-list***
> (regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
>
> (13.3) — Then, **non-static data members** are initialized 
> **in the order they were declared in the class definition** 
> (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
>
> (13.4) — Finally, the ***compound-statement*** of the constructor body is executed.

Terminology:

*`base-specifier-list`* - list of base classes for derived class. See section 10 of reference. 
Example: `class A :` **`public virtual B, private C`**

*`mem-initializers`* - list of initializers for members of your class. 
Example: `A::A() :` **`number(1.0f), text("abc")`**`{ /* ... */}`

*`compound-statement`* - block of `{}`, i.e. body of constructor.

---

That's all, simply said the order:

0. **static variables** (see this stackoverflow question [C++ static variables initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312371/c-static-variables-initialization-order), also that interesting behavior [SIOF](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)). In single translation unit order follows declaration order, in different - compilers decide.
1. **virtual base classes** as appear by dfs
2. **direct base classes** as specified by order in deriving list
3. **non-static variables** by declaration (! not initializers order) order