# C++ Initialization list and memory alloc

Tags: c++, constructor, memory-management, smart-pointers, initialization-list

Is the following valid?

```
class myClass
{
   private:
     ...
     int m_nDataLength;
     boost::shared_array<int> m_pData;
     ...

   public:
     myClass(): ..., m_nDataLength(10), m_pData(new int[m_nDataLength]), ...
     {
     }
}
```

Am I right in assuming that the initialization will happen exactly in the order I've given in the ctor? If not, what if m_nDataLength's initialization happens after m_pData's?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242830/constructor-initialization-list-evaluation-order .

Comment: I didn't notice this one, my question seems to be a duplicate of this one. Thanks for notifying Luc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the initialization in your example does happen in the order you want, it's not for the reason you assume: **Initialization happens in the order of the data members *declaration* in the class definition.** The reason for this is that the destructor must destroy the members in backward order not matter which constructor was used to create the object. For that, a constructor-independent way of defining the construction order must be used.

That means that, if instead of

```
class myClass
{
   private:
     ...
     int m_nDataLength;
     boost::shared_array<int> m_pData;
```

someone would change your code to

```
class myClass
{
   private:
     ...
     boost::shared_array<int> m_pData;
     int m_nDataLength;
```

then the code would have a bug.

My advice is:

- Write your constructors so that the initialiszation order doesn't matter.
- If you cannot do this (note: to me this happened less than 5 times in the last decade), make it completely clear at the point the data members are declared.

Something like this should do:

```
class myClass
{
   private:
     ...
     int m_nDataLength;                 // Note: Declaration order
     boost::shared_array<int> m_pData;  //       matters here!
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the answers here. It has fixed an annoying issue and was an eye-opener for me :)

But I voted this one for it's detail.

Answer (score 9):

the initialization will initialize fields by order in class, so: if you change

```
private:
  ...
  int m_nDataLength;
  boost::shared_array<int> m_pData;
```

as

```
private:
  ...
  boost::shared_array<int> m_pData;
  int m_nDataLength;
```

it wont work. In constructor, the order doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5):

No, initialization for class members happens in the order that the members appear in the class definition. If a member appears in the initializer list, then that controls the expression used to initialize that member (even if it uses a member that has not yet been initialized) but where it appears in the initializer list does not affect when it is initialized.