# C++: Initializing class member variable with reference to another class member variable?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initialization

I am attempting to make a class in c++ called to store values for a number of parameters that are organized as member variables of class 'Planet' and class 'Satellite', which I want to initialize with a reference to an instance of 'Planet'. Here I provide an example where I have a 'PlanetCatalog' class with 
 member variables 'Planet neptune' and a 'Satellite triton'.

```
class Planet {
    public:

    double a;

    Planet() {}

    void setParams(  const double a_) {
        a = a_;
    }
};


class Satellite {
    public:

    double b;

    Planet & planet;
    Satellite( Planet & planet_):planet(planet_) { }

    void setParams(const double b_) {
        b = b_;
    }
}; 

class PlanetCatalog {

    public:

    Planet neptune;
    Satellite triton(neptune);

    void setAll() {
        neptune.setParams(1.);
        triton.setParams(2.);
    }

};
```

However, upon compiling I encounter the error.

```
error: unknown type name 'neptune' 
    Satellite triton(neptune);
```

Is it possible to have the Planet and Satellite stored as variables of the same class as I have done here. If not, could someone suggest a better way of organizing this functionality in c++?

Comment: Create a constructor of your PlanetCatalog class

Answer (score 2):

Use of parentheses for in-class initialization makes compiler treat `triton` as a non-static member function declaration with `neptune` being type of the first argument, you should use *list-initialization* syntax instead:

```
Satellite triton{neptune};
```

Note that there is actually no need to define `PlanetCatalog` constructor for this.

Answer (score 1):

**What happened?**

> ```
> class PlanetCatalog {
> public:
>    ...
>    Planet neptune;
>    Satellite triton(neptune); //<-- Compiler sees this as a non-static member-function declaration
>    ...
> ```

Because of the context of that statement, the compiler sees it as a  non-static member-function declaration and tries to find such *type* named `neptune` within the relevant *namespace(s)*; It issues an error since it can't find it.

---

**Option 1**: You can define a constructor that initializes `triton` for you in its [*member-initialization-list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
class PlanetCatalog {
public:
   ...
   Planet neptune;
   Satellite triton;

   PlanetCatalog() : triton(neptune) {}
   ...
```

***Note:*** using this option, the [order of your class data members matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285112/why-must-initializer-list-order-match-member-declaration-order), because the order initialization of data members is defined by their order of declaration in the class, not by the order of initialization in the `member-initialization-list`

---

**Option 2**: Another straightforward solution will be to use [*copy-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

```
Satellite triton = neptune;
```

**Option 3**:  or [*list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

```
Satellite triton{neptune};
```

Options 2 and 3 are preferable because it forces the declaration order implicitly.

Comment: I was not familiar with list-initialization, but it looks like what I want. However if I just replace the line I had with 'triton(neptune)' to 'triton{neptune}'. I encounter the following error: 'error: function definition does not declare parameters'. In the documentation it seems like the example cases are using to initialize it with the same class ( i.e. planetA{planetB} and not SatelliteA{planetB} ). Should this work for my case? I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Are you using C++11? ... If you aren't using a veey recent compiler, you may need to add `-std=c++11` flag  in the command line invocation of your compiler; or IDE, build file, whatever... You can try more recent standards like `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17` if your compiler supports it