# Are initializer lists called before or after default constructors?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class `Alpha`, which has two member variables, `beta` and `gamma`, which are objects of classes `Beta` and `Gamma` respectively:

```
class Alpha
{
public:
    Beta beta_;
    Gamma gamma_;
};
```

Now, the class `Gamma` itself has a member variable `p_beta`, which is a pointer to that same `beta` variable in `Alpha`. However, `Gamma` does not have a default constructor, but instead it must be constructed by passing `p_beta`:

```
class Gamma
{
public:
    Beta* p_beta_;
    Gamma(Beta* p_beta)
    {
        p_beta_ = p_beta;
    }
};
```

So then, if I want to create an object `alpha` of class `Alpha`, I need to construct its member `gamma_` in the initializer list of `Alpha`, given that `Gamma` does not have a default constructor:

```
class Alpha
{
public:
    Beta beta_;
    Gamma gamma_;
    Alpha() : gamma_(&beta_){}
};
```

My question is: Will `beta_` have already been created by the time `gamma_` is constructed in this initializer list? I would have thought that the initializer list is called before creating any of the other member variables, in which case `beta_` will not exist. If `beta_` has not been created by then, then how can I pass a pointer to `beta_` when constructing `gamma_`?

Comment: realetd: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037219/order-of-execution-in-constructor-initialization-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-static non-variant data members of a class are initialized in declaration order, without exception. The fact that you haven't specified a *mem-initializer* for `beta_` simply means that it will be default-initialized, and this default initialization takes place *before* the initialization of `gamma_` because `beta_` precedes `gamma_` in declaration order.

Besides that, even if you changed the order of `beta_` and `gamma_` in the class definition, there's nothing wrong with passing around a pointer to an object that hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: _there's nothing wrong with passing around a pointer to an object that hasn't been initialized yet_: But beware! receivers of this pointer may want to use it, not just to store it for later, And then you will have UB.

Answer (score 2):

> Will `beta_` have already been created by the time `gamma_` is constructed in this initializer list?

Yes, `beta_` will have been default-constructed before `gamma_`, so it is safe to use its address. Initialization of non-static data members occurs in declaration order, and destruction in reverse-declaration order.

Answer (score 0):

From [class.base.init]/13, emphasis mine:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>   — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are...
>   — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order ...
>   — Then, non-static data members are initialized **in the order they were declared in the class definition**
>   (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).

So yes, `beta_` will have been constructed before `gamma_` (the order of the initializers is irrelevant)