# C++ member variable initializaton order

Tags: c++

can you tell me in which order the member variables of an object are initialized (constructor calls) and if the initialization list has an influence on it? For example if I instantiate:

```
 class Meta
 {

 public:
    Meta() : a(), b(),c(),d()
    {

    }

 private:

    SomeObject d;
    SomeObject c;
    SomeObject b;
    SomeObject a;
 };
```

Would the member variables be initialized in the order a,b,c,d  ( as in the initialization list) or d,c,b,a  (the order in which they are defined in the class) ? I'm experimenting with Visual Studio 2012 Debugger and my tests suggest the latter, but I'd like to know if I can influence it via the initialization list.

Regards

Comment: Not sure how to add another duplicate to the list above, but this is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037219/order-of-execution-in-constructor-initialization-list

Comment: This is not a duplicate, that's a quadruplicate!

Answer (score 3):

They're done in the order they're declared in, irrespective of the initializer list.