# Could someone explain this inheritance code?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    A() { cout << "A "; } 
};

struct B: A {
    B() { cout << "B "; }  
};

struct C: A {
    C() { cout << "C "; } 
};

struct D: C, B {
    D() { cout << "D "; }    
};

int main(){
    D d;
}
```

The result is A C A B D. 
My understanding is that D inherits from C and B, and if an object "d" is created in D, then it also has the attributes from C  and B. And since B and C both inherits from A, D should also inherit from A. Can someone explain the result please? My prediction is way off...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You should add a tag for the programming language so that the question shows up for people who are experts at that language.  :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip! I'm still new to SO ^^

Comment: @codenoob Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 1):

The base constructor(s) are called first, then the main constructor.

```
    D()
=>  C()    then  B()    then D
=>  A() C  then  A() B  then D
=>  A C    then  A B    then D
=>  A C A B D
```

[Order of execution in constructor initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4037283/1023602)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance reflects an IS A relationship.

A D object is a C and a B. A C is in turn an A. Therefore, to create an instance of D, the runtime has to first create an A and then a C. That explains the first two characters of the output. Continue with this reasoning and you'll get the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!