# C++ - Mixing default member initializers and member initialization lists - bad idea?

Tags: c++, c++11, member-initialization

This is partly a style question, partly a correctness question.  Submit the following sample (a strip-down of a class which deals with a block of data that contains an embedded header):

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(size_t size)
      : scratch_(new uint8_t[header_length_ + size]),
        size_(header_length_ + size) {
  }
  ~Foo() {
    delete[] scratch_;
  }
  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;  // Effective C++
  void operator=(const Foo&) = delete;  // Effective C++
 protected:
  struct Header {
    uint32_t a, b, c, d;
  };
  uint8_t * const scratch_;
  size_t const size_;
  Header * const header_ = reinterpret_cast<Header *>(scratch_);
  static constexpr size_t header_length_ = sizeof(Header);
  static constexpr size_t data_offset_ = header_length_;
  size_t const data_length_ = size_ - data_offset_;
};
```

First, technical correctness... is it correct that as written, `scratch_` and `size_` will be initialized first, then `header_`, then `data_length_`?  (`constexpr` items are compile-time literal constants and don't figure into initialization order.)  Is it also correct that **how** the initializer is declared, be it default member initialization (`int foo = 5`) or a member initializer list, has no impact on initialization order, but rather, what matters is solely the order in which members are declared?  I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037219/order-of-execution-in-constructor-initialization-list), citing the ISO spec regarding initialization order, and what I gathered is that it's unimportant that `scratch_` and `size_` appear in the member initialization list versus other members that are given default member initializers; it only matters that `scratch_` and `size_` are declared before the other members.  Presumably if `scratch_` and `size_` were declared last, then `header_` and `data_length_` would (undesirably/incorrectly) be initialized first.

Style question... is it bad style to mix these two initialization styles?  My approach is that items in the member initialization list (`scratch_`, `size_`) depend on the argument(s) passed into the constructor, while the remaining class members are derived from other class members.  Obviously, if an initializer depends on a constructor argument, then it **has** to go into a member initialization list.  Should I throw **all** initializers into the member initialization list regardless, and abandon default member initializers?  IMO, that may make the code a little harder to follow.  Thoughts?

Comment: I believe it's correct .. don't find it very aesthetic personally but others may differ

Comment: Should be `delete[] scratch_;`

Comment: "*traditional initialization*" There is nothing "traditional" about default member initializers.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I was struggling to come up with a canonical name for those, versus items in member initialization lists.  "Default member initializers" is what I should call them, then?

Comment: @DavidR: [Yes.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Comment: @DavidR: The "member" part of "default member initializer" is really important.

Comment: The proper name is *brace-or-equal-initializer*

Comment: @M.M: No, it isn't. `brace-or-equal-initializer` is the syntactic construct that allows you to initialize them. The application of that syntax to a non-static data member is officially called a "default member initailizer": "*A brace-or-equal-initializer for a non-static
data member specifies a **default member initializer** for the member*". This term was added in C++17.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The presence of [default member initializers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) changes nothing about the order in which subobjects of a type are initialized. It will *always* be in declaration order.

Style is up to you. The more constructors you have, the more you gain by using DMIs, since you're not repeating initialization that doesn't change. At the same time, if you start making constructors that override DMIs, that can create confusion about what the object's initial state is. The key is to try not to be surprising about what's going on.

In your particular case however, I'd say that you have too many variables. Your array should just be a `std::vector<uint8_t>`. Having the `header_` pointer is dubious but defensible (though it's initialized incorrectly; you need to use placement-new to satisfy C++'s object model). But `data_length_` can be computed on an as-needed basis.

The fewer members you have, the less chance for confusion about how they get initialized.

Comment: I'm learning C++ having come from 20 years of writing embedded C, plus some C# and a tiny bit of C++ in the late 90s.  Very apt points.  I get it about DMIs and multiple constructors; I also saw from the one link you gave that a constructor's member initializer will override a DMI, which makes sense.  placement new makes complete sense; it's a language-correct means of doing overlays, without abusing pointers as I'm doing.  And re: too many variables, I'm likely guilty of premature optimization; one-line functions aren't much of a performance penalty. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

It has been advised in all forums, class members irrespective whether const or non-const initialize with initializer list. In your case it may not be an issue, but when the class used for extension it can give problem.