# initialize a member variable inside of constructor? (this should be very basic...)

Tags: c++

Edit: I need to refactor this question, it has too many extraneous components to be clear what my question (which is about C++) is. But anyone who can understand what I am asking please do answer.

I have a class which represents a thread. The threading library I am using, TinyThread++, starts a thread by creating a `thread` object, however there is no copy constructor for it. Which makes sense.. What would be the meaning of copying a thread anyway?

Previously I had been initializing my thread object `E_thread` this way:

```
class E_thread {
    E_threadRoutine m_routine;
    E_thread *m_parent;
    thread m_thread;
public:
    E_thread(void *(void*),void*,E_thread*);
};
E_thread::E_thread(void *func(void*), void *arg, E_thread* parent): 
         m_parent(parent), m_routine(func,arg), 
         m_thread(thread_function_common, &m_routine) 
         {}
```

Initializing the `thread` ctor in this fashion works, I am sending the pointer of the `E_thread`'s `m_routine` member to the thread as its argument. The purpose of `m_routine` is to keep track of thread specific functionality to pass to the thread itself.

However now I want to make a change where I want to allocate `m_routine` more carefully. Now `m_routine` is a pointer and I will need to set it with

```
m_routine = new E_threadRoutineTypeX(func,arg,etc);
```

in the `E_thread` ctor body. But this means I can no longer initialize `thread` the way I have been. I tried putting

```
m_thread = thread(thread_function_common,m_routine);
```

in the body but this copies the thread object which I don't want to do. There's gotta be some syntax for doing this....

Comment: Could I do this? `E_thread::E_thread(void *func(void*), void *arg, E_thread* parent): m_parent(parent), m_routine(new E_threadRoutine(func,arg)), m_thread(thread_function_common, &m_routine) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following: initialize m_routine using a function, that will return a new  E_threadRoutine like so -

```
m_routine(createThreadRoutine(func, arg))
```

and have createThreadRoutine return a new E_threadRoutine whichever way you want. Then, you can initialize m_thread with (thread_function_common, m_routine). The use of createThreadRoutine is not mandatory, but it will let you do more than just a `new`, if that's needed.

For this to work, m_routine must appear before m_thread in the class, otherwise m_thread will be initialize before m_routine is set. See [Constructor initialization-list evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242830/constructor-initialization-list-evaluation-order).

Comment: This hadn't occurred to me and it makes sense. Is there no syntax that allows me to initialize in the body itself??

Comment: @Steven Lu, I'm not sure I understand your question, but in the initialization list you basically call the constructor of the member variables. If you want to initialize them in the body of E_thread's constructor, just use pointers as your member variables. Then, you could `new` the variables in E_thread's constructor, in whatever order you like, with whatever arguments.

Comment: Yes, i could do it that way, but I'm bothered by the fact that there doesn't seem to be any provision for allowing initialization of a member variable (by using its constructor) in the body of the constructor. The constructor is, after all, the place where things are meant to be initialized!

Answer (score 1):

```
class E_thread {
    E_threadRoutine* m_routine;
    E_thread *m_parent;
    thread m_thread;
public:
    E_thread(void *(void*),void*,E_thread*);
};
E_thread::E_thread(void *func(void*), void *arg, E_thread* parent) : 
    m_routine(new E_threadRoutineTypeX(func,arg,etc)), 
    m_parent(parent),
    m_thread(thread_function_common, m_routine) 
{}
```

I also changed your member initialization order, it should always occur in the order the members appear in the class to help avoid errors.