# Simplest way to initialize multiple related const properties in a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

When multiple const properties of a C++ class depend on some intermediate calculation, what is the simplest way to initialize them?

For example, how do I correct the constructor for the class below?

```
class MyClass {
public:
    const int a;
    const int b;

    MyClass() {
        int relatedVariable = rand() % 250;
        a = relatedVariable % 100;
        b = abs(relatedVariable - 150);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can the expression for `relatedVariable` be made external to the class? So that you could pass it as a parameter into the constructor.

Comment: Look into initialization lists in c++

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With C++11, you can simply use a delegating constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    const int a;
    const int b;

private:
    MyClass( int relatedVariable )
      : a( relatedVariable % 100 ),
        b( abs( relatedVariable - 150 ) ) {}

public:
    MyClass() : MyClass( rand() % 250 ) {}
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a roundabout solution using delegating constructors:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(int aa, int bb) : a(aa), b(bb) { }

    static MyClass Maker() { int x = /* ... */; return MyClass(x * 2, x * 3); }

    int const a;
    int const b;

public:
    MyClass(MyClass const &) = default;
    MyClass() : MyClass(Maker()) { }
};
```

Comment: @ulidtko: Try compiling with a current (as in bleeding edge) compiler and c++11 features turned on for that delegating constructor.

Comment: @ulidtko: This uses C++11 features. Your compiler might not support those.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I used gcc 4.6, but delegating constructors are supported only in 4.7+.

Comment: That looks too complicated, see my answer for an easier solution using delegating constructors.

Comment: @DanielFrey: that looks good. I suppose my version is a little more extensible, but for the OP's example yours is much nicer.

Answer (score 3):

This will kinda *work* for those of us who happen to prefer being less advanced in their coding:

```
class MyClass {
public:

    int iamStupid;      /* K.I.S.S. */

    const int a;
    const int b;

    MyClass()
      : iamStupid(rand() % 250)
      , a(iamStupid % 150)
      , b(abs(iamStupid - 150))
    {}
};
```

The additional member presents an unnecessary overhead — which may or may not be significant for the task at hand. OTOH, the code is simple.

Remember to declare `iamStupid` **before** `a` and `b`! (see comments)

Comment: [Member variables are initialized in the order of their declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1242845/201270). Therefore this would initialize `a` and `b` before initializing `relatedVariable`, which kind of defeats its purpose.

Comment: @Grizzly, correct. I should've declared `relatedVariable` before `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this - not pretty but should do the trick:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    const int a;
    const int b;
    static int relatedVariable;
    MyClass() :
        a(setRand()),
        b(relatedVariable)  {}
    static const int setRand()
    {
        relatedVariable = rand() % 250;
        return relatedVariable;
    }
};
int MyClass::relatedVariable = 0;
```

Comment: Why separate function for `rand() % 250`? You could use that in the initializer directly.

Comment: This isn't threadsafe.  Probably doesn't matter, but just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

In case if you are stuck with an ancient compiler which doesn't support delegating constructors, here's the same approach adapted for the older language version:

```
class MyClassBase {
public:
    const int a;
    const int b;
    MyClassBase(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};

class MyClass : public MyClassBase {
    static MyClassBase Maker() {
        int x = rand() % 250;
        return MyClassBase(x % 100, abs(x - 150));
    }
public:
    using MyClassBase::a;
    using MyClassBase::b;

    MyClass() : MyClassBase(Maker()) { }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an intermediate class that does the calculation:

```
class ConstCalc {

   public:
    ConstCalc(int related) : rv(related){}

    int a() const { return rv % 100; } 
    int b() const { return abs( rv - 150 ) ; } 

   private:
    const int rv;
};

class MyClass {
public:
    const int a;
    const int b;

    MyClass( const ConstCalc c ) : a( c.a() ), b( c.b() ) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Const is a contract between a class's user and implementor. It indicates that the class user should not modify the member variables, thus providing an immutable object design. It is fine for a constructor to otherwise initialize that state. That said, it might be better to hide these behind a private access qualifier and to provide accessors that allow read-only. The correct way to temporarily remove const-ness is using the const_cast<>.

```
class MyClass {
public:
   const int a;
   const int b;

MyClass() : a(0), b(0) {
    int relatedVariable = rand() % 250;
    const_cast<int&>(a) = relatedVariable % 100;
    const_cast<int&>(b) = abs(relatedVariable - 150);
}
```

};

Comment: Is there any performance impact for this solution? Won't the compiler now assume that a and b aren't really const?

Comment: It is doubtful that you will see any performance change at all. "const-ness" inside of a class is a compile-time notion.

Comment: @jbruni, are you sure this is strictly legal? IIRC `const_cast` is only well-defined if the object itself is not `const` (i.e. you can cast a `const T&` to `T&` only if the reference refers to an object not originally declared `const`)

Comment: @jbruni see the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe ; also, the quote "§7.1.​5.1/4 says Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior"

Comment: yeah, this is explicitly UB, so i had to vote accordingly

Answer (score -1):

You could make `a` and `b` private, and provide getters to access their values from outside the class.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int a, b; // private
public:
    int getA() { return a; }
    int getB() { return b; }

    MyClass()
    {
        int relatedVariable = rand() % 250;
        a = relatedVariable % 100;
        b = abs(relatedVariable - 150);
    }
};
```

Or, you could just use subobject initializers and cache the random number somehow.  Turning the optimization on might even remove the temporary variable in the generated program text.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int temp; // this is a workaround
public:
    const int a;
    const int b;

    MyClass() : temp(rand() % 250), a(temp % 100), b(abs(temp - 150)) {}
};
```

[Remember that subobject construction happens in the order that members are declared in the class, and that the order of subobjects in the initialization list is ignored.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242830/constructor-initialization-list-evaluation-order)

Or, you can be lazy, and only store the initial random number, and generate `a, b` on demand.

Comment: *"will probably detect the overlapping computation"* - it won't, because `rand()` has side effects.

Comment: But `rand()` is only called once.  Any method of caching the result will produce the same output, regardless of what bizarre trick is used to do it.  The memory `a, b` will not be mapped into read-only memory, and what the optimizer does to it is its own prerogative.  But I see what you mean and I'll reword it.