# Is a pointer to string literal guaranteed to be initialized before a std::string?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-initialization

```
//file1.cpp
extern const char* foo;
std::string bar = foo;

//file2.cpp
const char* foo = "foo";
```

Is bar guaranteed by the standard to be initialized to `"foo"`? Or could it be initialized before `foo` gets set and segfault in the constructor i.e. a case of SIOF?

Comment: I don't think it's irrelevant since I've seen some quirks in the rules for converting string literals to pointers before (especially relating to `constexpr`) so it might be a special case here too.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312371/c-static-variables-initialization-order (I still expect that there is a dupe somewhere).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constant initialization is guaranteed to happen first (`foo` in this case).

So

> Is bar guaranteed by the standard to be initialized to "foo"?

Yes.

> Or could it be initialized before foo gets set and segfault in the
>   constructor i.e. a case of SIOF?

No.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization

Comment: How is this answer different to mine? "If in your case both are global, the std::string bar will always be initialised to "foo" because bar depends on foo during the compiler stage"

Comment: I am concerned that this is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312371/c-static-variables-initialization-order and http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start#static-3.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit the reply in the moment. The variable is non-static, it is merely const.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Is it guaranteed that no early dynamic initialization happens here? I can't wrap my head around http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start#static-3.2...

Comment: @MaxLanghof In practice this doesn't happen though because compilers don't see across TUs :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Well, link time optimization is a thing, no?

Comment: @MaxLanghof The example is explained better in cppreference, see if that clears up your questions :). I have no idea if LTO does that.