# Initialise const int and object with that const int in the same constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

I have an object that is created in a .h file that should be initialised in the constructor. This object is passed a COM port number that is 5 in our current application. For this reason I have created a const int in the .h file.

**Edit: I added a more complete example**

```
class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB(int comPort);
private:
    int m_comPort;
};

ClassB::ClassB(int comPort) :
    m_comPort(comPort)
{
}

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA();
private:
    const int comPort;
    ClassB B;
};

ClassA::ClassA() :
    comPort(5),
    B(comPort)
{
}

int main()
{
    ClassA A;
    return 0;
}
```

Because the object is initialised before comPort is fully initialised, the value for comPort is garbage.

What would be the correct way to circumvent this? I can think of the following:

- Initialise the const int in the header file
- Create and initialise the object in the body of the constructor
- use a #define

Comment: If `comPort` is defined in the class before `B` then it wouldn't be garbage. There isn't enough information here to answer your question or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will edit in a more complete example, apologies!

Comment: Added a more elaborate code example.

Comment: I do not see how you are getting garbage here.  The code looks correct.

Comment: Sorry I missed the const in the hurry of providing a proper example, should be fixed now.

Comment: The example is correct, can you be more specific as to what you are asking? Are you asking for other ways of achieving the same thing?

Comment: It should still work just fine.  Is it the `m_comPort` that you see the issue with?

Comment: Strange, I do not get garbage in my test program but I get it in my actual code. Might be something else in play. Indeed like you both say the code seems fine the way it is. I will check the main code again. @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @YouKnowNothingJohn Are you sure you declare `comPort` before `B` in `classA`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah, you mean in the header file? That could be it. Maybe it is switched in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reproduce your error if you exchange declaration of `comPort` and `B` in definition of `ClassA`. See this comment on SO concerning [Constructor initialization-list evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1242835/2630032).

Hence, make sure that if an initializer list relies on a specific order of evaluation, then the declaration of the members to be initialized must adhere to this order.

Comment: As Francois mentioned in the comments, I believe this was the culprit!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a problem with the order your members are initialized. Class members are initialized *in the order they are declared*. The order they are initialized in the constructor does not override this. In the next example `bar::my_foo` is initialized before `bar::my_const`, which will cause problems. `my_foo` will be initialized with an unitialized `my_const` member;

```
struct foo {
    foo(int p_x) : x(p_x) {}
    int x;
}

struct bar {
    bar() : my_const(5), my_foo(my_const) {}
    foo my_foo;
    const int my_const;
}
```

The problem can be fixed by changing order the members are declared.

```
struct bar {
    bar() : my_const(5), my_foo(my_const) {}
    const int my_const; // my_const before my_foo
    foo my_foo;
}
```

Comment: A less brittle approach would be to not rely on the order at all.  `bar(const int var = 5) : my_const(var), my_foo(var) {}` gets rid of any dependency.