# why i am not getting output using the toString method of my class?

Tags: c++

Date.h

```
#include <string>

#ifndef DATE_H_
#define DATE_H_

class Date
{
public:
    static const unsigned int monthsPerYear{12};
    explicit Date(unsigned int d = 1, unsigned int m = 1, unsigned int y = 1900);
    std::string toString() const;
private:
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int checkDay(unsigned int ) const;
};


#endif /* DATE_H_ */
```

Date.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <array>
#include "Date.h"

using namespace std;

Date::Date(unsigned int d, unsigned int m, unsigned int y) : day{checkDay(d)}, month{m}, year{y} {
    if ( month < 1 || month > monthsPerYear ) {
        throw invalid_argument("wrong entry for month");
    }
}

string Date :: toString() const {
    ostringstream output;
    output << day << ":" << month << "/" << year;
    return output.str();
}

unsigned int Date :: checkDay(unsigned int testDay) const {
    static const array<unsigned, monthsPerYear + 1> daysPerMonth{0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    if (testDay <= daysPerMonth[month] && testDay > 0) {
        return testDay;
    }
    return testDay;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Date d2;
    cout << d2.toString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i get nothing in the output console.

Comment: Instead of creating a `toString` member function, why don't you overload `operator<<`? So you can simply do `cout << d2 << '\n';`

Comment: You also have *undefined behavior* because you use `month` before it has been initialized in the `checkDay` function.

Comment: In future please present your MCVE as a single file (as I show in my answer, but better) so that we don't have to merge it ourselves when plugging it into a compiler.

Comment: Use `int`, not `unsigned int`. Using unsigned numbers breaks your error checking; for example, `month < 1` will never be true (unless it's zero), because if someone passes a negative number to your constructor, it will have been converted to a positive number by the point you perform the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [initilization list order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242830/constructor-initialization-list-evaluation-order). The order of the variables in your class declaration dictates the order of assignment in the constructor. Simply arrange **month** to come before **day** in your class declaration:

```
private:
unsigned int month;
unsigned int day;
```

Comment: Then flip the initialisations around to get rid of the compiler warning.

Comment: actually i just did that and it worked, and yes need to flip around for compiler waring

Comment: @munish Yes but if you look at my answer you'll see that there is a better way that results in a superior design. You should never have to alter your data layout or external API to work around strange designs like you have now. That makes for a fragile codebase.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see anything wrong with this other than the UB that *Some programmer dude* identified, and [I do get output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7dcb370b2a7a6f5) (after transforming your snippets into a single-file testcase).

You can fix the UB by making `checkDay` take both day *and* month:

```
unsigned int checkDay(unsigned int, unsigned int) const;
```

and:

```
Date::Date(unsigned int d, unsigned int m, unsigned int y) : day{checkDay(d, m)}, month{m}, year{y} {
```

and:

```
unsigned int Date :: checkDay(unsigned int testDay, unsigned int testMonth) const {
    static const array<unsigned, monthsPerYear + 1> daysPerMonth{0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    if (testDay <= daysPerMonth[testMonth] && testDay > 0) {
        return testDay;
    }
    return testDay;
}
```

Alternatively initialise `month` *before* calling the function (you'll have to declare `month` before `day` too, then) but I think the solution above has better symmetry given what the function does. I'd actually consider making `checkDay` a `static` member function now too.

Then [it should work reliably](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23e97c7c42a08ee8).

Of course, for a non-learning program, you would be using `boost::gregorian::date`. :)