# Is there a reason to call a base class constructor before member initializers other than it is good practice?

Tags: c++

Given the types

```
struct A
{ 
    A(int);
};

struct B : A 
{ 
    int x;
    B();
};
```

is there any impactful reason to prefer the call to the constructor of `A` before the initialization of `x`? By impactful I mean effect on the behavior on the program rather than "it's good/common practice to do so".

```
B::B() : A(10), x(5) { }

// can this difference affect the programs behavior somehow?

B::B() : x(5), A(10) { }
```

The [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init) doesn't seem to forbid or reason about this, so I assume reordering the mem-initializer-list is well defined.

Comment: `A`'s initialization happens first no matter what. Warnings about this are just so you don't accidentally rely on the order of the members in the list. For example, `x(5), A(x)` won't work because `x` will be uninitialized when `A(x)` happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor initialization-list evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242830/constructor-initialization-list-evaluation-order)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Don't you mean that the base class will be initialized first? Then, subsequently, member variables will be initialized in declaration order.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think he was trying to point out that such an initialization would be ill-formed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's what I meant by *"A's initialization happens first no matter what."* `A` is the base class, it will be initialized first.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm an idiot. I was reading your comment too quickly on my phone and read `A` as `x`. My apologies.